# Javascript executes functions inside classes unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, html

I have  a Modal class to show and hide the modal respectively. This class has two functions inside; open() and close(). I've related these functions with the openModal() function and added this function to onclick of the image div. When I click on the image a bigger image inside the modal shows up but when I want to close the modal, it closes the modal and runs the open() function again. So it seems like close button is not working.

**My class;**

```
class Modal {
    constructor(overlay) {
        this.overlay = overlay;
        const closeButton = overlay.querySelector('.button-close')
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this));
        overlay.addEventListener('click', e => {
            this.close();
        });
    }
    open() {
        this.overlay.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    }
    close() {
        this.overlay.classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
}
```

**How i call this function inside the `main.js`**

```
const modal = new Modal(document.querySelector('.modal-overlay'));
window.openModal = modal.open.bind(modal);
```

**Image div**

```
<div onClick="openModal()" class="item3"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' id="${id}" src="${namImage}">
  <div class="is-hidden modal-overlay">
    <div class="image-modal">
       <span class="button-close">×</span>
      <img src="${namImage}" width="95%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need a review on this issue.

Thank you
H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.button-close` is inside the `.modal-overlay`, so although a click on it will trigger the `close` function, it will also trigger the `open` function because the click was also on the `.modal-overlay`. Call `stopPropagation` in the `close` function:

```
close(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.overlay.classList.add('is-hidden');
}
```

```js
class Modal {
    constructor(overlay) {
        this.overlay = overlay;
        const closeButton = overlay.querySelector('.button-close')
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this));
        overlay.addEventListener('click', e => {
            this.close();
        });
    }
    open() {
        this.overlay.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    }
    close(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.overlay.classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
}

const modal = new Modal(document.querySelector('.modal-overlay'));
window.openModal = modal.open.bind(modal);
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div onClick="openModal()" class="item3"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' id="${id}" src="${namImage}">
  <div class="is-hidden modal-overlay">
    <div class="image-modal">
       <span class="button-close">× (CLICK TO CLOSE)</span>
      <img src="${namImage}" width="95%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You also might consider attaching all listeners properly with Javascript, rather than with inline handlers:

```js
class Modal {
    constructor(overlay) {
        this.overlay = overlay;
        const closeButton = overlay.querySelector('.button-close')
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this));
        overlay.addEventListener('click', e => {
            this.close();
        });
    }
    open() {
        this.overlay.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    }
    close(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.overlay.classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
}

const modal = new Modal(document.querySelector('.modal-overlay'));
modal.overlay.parentElement.onclick = modal.open.bind(modal);
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item3"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' id="${id}" src="${namImage}">
  <div class="is-hidden modal-overlay">
    <div class="image-modal">
       <span class="button-close">× (CLICK TO CLOSE)</span>
      <img src="${namImage}" width="95%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
class Modal {
    open(mod) {
        mod.querySelector('.modal-overlay').classList.remove('is-hidden');
    }
    close(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
}

const modal = new Modal();
```

```css
.is-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div onClick="modal.open(this)" class="item3"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' id="'${id}'" src="${namImage}">
  Click me to open modal
  <div class="is-hidden modal-overlay">
    <div class="image-modal">
       <span class="button-close" onclick="modal.close(event)">× click here to close</span>
      <img src="${namImage}" width="95%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It handles multi-modal case

```js
class Modal {
    open(mod) {
        mod.querySelector('.modal-overlay').classList.remove('is-hidden');
    }
    close(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
}

const modal = new Modal();
```

```css
.is-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div onClick="modal.open(this)" class="item3"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' id="'${id}'" src="${namImage}">
  Click me to open modal ONE
  <div class="is-hidden modal-overlay">
    <div class="image-modal">
       <span class="button-close" onclick="modal.close(event)">× click here to close</span>
      <img src="${namImage}" width="95%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div onClick="modal.open(this)" class="item3"><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' id="'${id}'" src="${namImage}">
  Click me to open modal TWO
  <div class="is-hidden modal-overlay">
    <div class="image-modal">
       <span class="button-close" onclick="modal.close(event)">× click here to close</span>
      <img src="${namImage}" width="95%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```